# Accessing array object from cookie in node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies

In angular.js, I have set a cookie with array object as below:

```
if($cookies.get(uid )== undefined)
{
    var arr =[];
    $cookies.put("arr",arr);
    $cookies.put("uid","abc");
    console.log("=========cookies.uid"+$cookies.get(uid));
}
```

But when accessing it in node.js, it is undefined:

```
if(req.cookies.uid!=req.session.value)
{
    var u =  uuid.v1();
    req.session.value = u;
    res.cookie("uid",u);
    var ar =  null;
*** console.log("req.cookies.arr"+req.cookies.arr); ***// it is undefined 
    ar = req.cookies.arr;
    ar.push(req.query.d);
    res.cookie("arr",ar);

    console.log("session cookie val="+u);
}
```

The line marked with *** is giving undefined on the first place and so I can't push on to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON, since cookie value can only be strings.

Client side

```
var arr =[];
$cookies.put("arr",JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Server side

```
ar = JSON.parse(req.cookies.arr);
ar.push(req.query.d);
```